# VB.Net how to prevent listbox firing selectedindexchanged selectedvaluechanged on load

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Help, When I set datasource to listbox it fires selectedindexchanged and selectedvaluechanged. How can I prevent this because this resets my value to the first item all the time

```
Dim SQLString As String
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim Properties As New Properties
SQLString = "select v.attributevalue,v.value"
SQLString += " from Table "
SQLString += " Where v.attributename ='new_vehicle'"
SQLString += " order by v.value"
getDataBySQL(SQLString, dt)
lstCategory.ValueMember = "attributevalue"
lstCategory.DisplayMember = "value"
lstCategory.DataSource = dt
Dim i As Integer = ReadDataFromDatabase
If i <> 0 Then
    lstCategory.SelectedValue = i
End If
Private Sub lstCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCategory.SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub
Private Sub lstCategory_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCategory.SelectedValueChanged
    SetDataToDatabase(lstCategory.SelectedValue.ToString)
End Sub
```

also when I set valuemember to the listbox it fires selectedvaluechanged.

Essentially I want to read the database value so when I have the listbox loaded it switch the selected value to what is the value in the database

Variable i is the selectedValue I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when I develop an application, I will create a Boolean variable called IsLoading and set it to false by default.  I will flag this as true before any code that may be loading data and mark it as false when completed.  In most cases this is in my Page Load.

```
Private Sub Form_Main_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    IsLoading = True

    'Code to load my data goes here

    IsLoading = False

End Sub
```

I will then add it to my dropdowns like so:

```
Private Sub lstCategory_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCategory.SelectedValueChanged
    If Not IsLoading Then
        SetDataToDatabase(lstCategory.SelectedValue.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

So anything the IsLoading flag is false, the code will be allowed to run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yea. this is simple and it will work. I was wondering if there is an equivalent like selectedChangecommited...  thanks for the suggestion.